# What did i do wrong? Trigonmetry and algebra

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question where I need to find perpendicular gradient and new points on a line. What I have is a triangle. I'm given no angles or lengths. I had to draw another triangle around it.

First I had to find the gradient of one side of the inner triangle which I successfully did, then I needed to find the new point on the outer triangle. I successfully did this too, but now when I need to do the same on the other side, its not working, even when I copy what I did before.

---

**HERE IS MY WORKING**

> The point I chose to work with was $(21,10)$ and the perpendicular distance between the two triangles is $1.2$m
>
> $\tan \theta=\mathrm{gradient}$
>
> $\theta=\arctan (-8.5/5)$
>
> $\theta= -59.53$
>
> $\theta=59.53$
>
> $180-90-59.53=30.47$
>
> $\sin\theta=\frac OH$
>
> $\sin 59.53=\frac b{1.2}$
>
> $b=(\sin59.53)(1.2)$
>
> $b=1.03$
>
> $\sin\theta=\frac OH$
>
> $\sin30.47=a/1.2$
>
> $a=(\sin30.47)(1.2)$
>
> $a=0.61$
>
> $a=0.61$
>
> $b=1.03$
>
> original points are $(21,10)$
>
> $21-0.61=20.39$
>
> $10+1.03=11.03$
>
> New points are $(20.39,11.03)$ I also found the gradient before to be $-1.3$
>
> $then I do $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$
>
> $y-11.03=-1.3 (x-20.39)$
>
> $y-11.03=-1.3x + 26.507$
>
> $y=-1.3x+37.537$

---

**This equation however, does not work properly when I put it into my graphing program. See below**

[image: Enter image description here[1]]

---

**I'm starting to think my points are wrong but I'm not sure. Can someone please help me**

[image: Enter image description here[2]]

Comment: sorry which bit?

Comment: is that better?

Comment: this is the question in case you dont understand what i have done Refer to page 5 for the bird’s eye view of Tom’s Park. The council has asked that a triangular sail be erected above the play equipment in the children’s playground to offer some shade during the day. Three posts will be placed at the vertices of the triangular sail. In order to keep costs down, the three posts that the sail is attached to must be positioned so that the perpendicular distance from the outermost point of the play equipment to the edge of the sail lies between 1 m and 1.3 m.

Comment: If the edges of the sail can be approximated by straight lines, determine the equations of the straight lines marking the edges of the shade sail as well as the position of the 3 posts so that the council requirements are met.  Ensure you include any domain restrictions on the equations marking the edges of the sail as well as sufficient algebraic working to justify the positioning of the posts. The post positions can be rounded to 1 decimal place.

Comment: that was meant to be multiplication sign

Comment: is it too confusing?

Comment: can you give diagram of the question or post **original** question

Comment: the original question is in the comments above and sure, i can post what we are given. Its at the bottom of all my working out